# onRequestPermissionsResult not being triggered for overlay permission

Tags: android

I'm trying to get onRequestPermissionsResult() to trigger so I can start running my application once I receive the overlay permission. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get onRequestPermissionsResult() to be called as the toast is not being sent. I feel this has to do with the fact that there is not accept or deny dialog box when you ask for an overlay permission. Instead you are presented with a toggle button.

[image: Permission]

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION = 1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRequestPermissionsResult has been called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "RequestCode: " + requestCode + " permissions " + permissions + " grantresults: " + grantResults, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void runService()
    {
        Intent svc = new Intent(this, OverlayShowingService.class);
        startService(svc);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you use `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`.

First, `startActivityForResult()` does not trigger `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

Second, `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` does not return a result.

So, just call `startActivity()` on your `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` `Intent`. The user will get the screen shown in your screenshot (or the equivalent for the user's devices). The user can elect to toggle that switch or not. Later, when control returns to your app (e.g., `onStart()`, `onResume()`), you can [call `canDrawOverlays()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#canDrawOverlays(android.content.Context)) to see if the user granted the permission or not.

Comment: this is not correct information , as i have been using it for a while in my app , startActivity() triggers on activityresult() , but it some devices like huawei it this !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this) does not work in onactivity result

Comment: @Quicklearner: "startActivity() triggers on activityresult()" -- first, that is not what your answer shows. Second, **the question** shows the OP expecting `startActivityForResult()` to trigger `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. That is what I was referring to in my answer, as that does not work.

Comment: startActivity() triggers on activityresult() ,i meant startActivityforResult()  , its my bad, anyways it triggers on activityResult() which is the way to check if the permissions is granted or rejected like i answered in my question

Comment: i just wanted to correct you by this statement " just call startActivity() on your ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION Intent. The user will get the screen shown in your screenshot (or the equivalent for the user's devices)." , as on using startActivityForResult it will trigger the onActivityResult , where the pemission granted /rejected can be handled, rather than just using startActivity

Comment: you can just try my answer and check the behaviour , huawei phone or xiaomi may behave differently due the their customized OS which i actually faced while testing

Comment: its just not good to call canDrawOverlays() in onResume() unless there is not option left , why not using the right way first i think , Thanks for sharing your knowledge